# show client validation message for input file upload size limit using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

I am trying validate upload file limit to 2.5 mb max. I need to show validation message on `<span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Attachement" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>` when focus lost from the field.

right now I am validating at client side like this.

```
 <div class="col-sm-7">
    <input class="form-control" id="Attachement" name="Attachement" type="file" value="">
    <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Attachement" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
  </div>

var attachement = document.getElementById('Attachement');
attachement.onchange = function() {
    var file = attachement.files[0];
    if (file.size > 2621440) {
         //Now Here I need to update <span> 

       alert('Filesize must 2.5mb or below'); // don't want alert message
    }
};
```

### example

```
<div class="col-sm-7">
  <input class="form-control valid" data-val="true" data-val-required="The First Name field is required." id="FirstName" name="FirstName" placeholder="First Name" required="required" type="text" value="">
  <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="FirstName" data-valmsg-replace="true" style="color:Red"></span>
</div>
```

after validation

```
<div class="col-sm-7">
  <input class="form-control input-validation-error" data-val="true" data-val-required="The First Name field is required." id="FirstName" name="FirstName" placeholder="First Name" required="required" type="text" value="">
  <span class="field-validation-error" data-valmsg-for="FirstName" data-valmsg-replace="true" style="color:Red"><span for="FirstName" class="">
        The First Name field is required.</span>
  </span>
</div>
```

and also update css class from `<input class="form-control"...` to  `<input class="form-control input-validation-error"...` to highlight the textbox to red.

How to do in jquery?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there's a jQuery equivalent to `file.size`, but you can simply get the DOM object from the jQuery object with `.get()` and use the Javascript property.

```
$("#Attachement").change(function() {
    var file = $(this).get(0);
    if (file.size && file.size > 2621440) {
        $(this).addClass("input-validation-error").siblings(".field_validation-valid").text("File must be smaller than 2.5MB.");
    } else {
        $(this).removeClass("input-validation-error").siblings(".field_validation-valid").empty();
    }
}
```

Comment: yes, I got that part. But how to update the `span` to show validation message.

Comment: Updated to show that. I didn't think you needed help with basic jQuery features, I thought you just wanted to know how to check the file size.